# After deploying Habitat to Azure I am getting rendering error

Tags: azure, deployment, habitat

While opening the item in the Experience editor I am getting a lot of errors like the below:

> Error Rendering View: /Views/MediaFeature/LightboxVideo.cshtml: Error
>   while rendering view: '/Views/MediaFeature/LightboxVideo.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
>   
> at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter
>   writer) 
> at
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) Inner
>   Exception:
>   
> d:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\MediaFeature\LightboxVideo.cshtml(7):
>   error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
>  
> at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() 
> at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() 
> at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) at
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed by adding the below to the `web.config`:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, 
        Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, only in if language is `C#`, in case if you are using `VB` then you can also use the below code.

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <!--For C# -->
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
        <!--For VB -->
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```